# Can I use different forms of authentication to log into my user account on a linux machine?

Tags: login, authentication

I want to create a mobile app that allows me to log in to my pc using the fingerprint reader and I am wondering whether I can add authentication methods to my user account.

I am thinking about writing a daemon that runs on startup (as root process) that listens for authentication requests coming in from my mobile device. **Could that script possibly supply authentication to the desktop environment's login manager or would that be a security risk?** If it's not possible, **would I have to integrate this authentication method "more deeply" into the desktop environment?**

Note: I am on KDE neon but I am looking for a generic answer if that's possible.

Comment: You're looking for [PAM](http://www.linux-pam.org/)

Comment: @muru Oh wow thank you, will look into it and answer my own question with the steps involved if no one else has done it until then.

Comment: As an example, here's how to set up PAM to use Google Authenticator. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Google_Authenticator